# Calculus Maximal Domain

Tags: calculus

Hi just a quick question regarding maximal domain.

Find the maximal domain of the following function

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{64-x^6}{\left(64-x^2\right)\left(64+x^2\right)\left(64+x^3\right)}$.

What should I be looking out for and how do I identify the perimeters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the denominator not equal to zero to get all the $x$-values that are not included in the domain:

- $64-x^2\ne0 \Rightarrow x\ne\pm8$
- $64+x^2\ne0 \Rightarrow $ no real solutions
- $64+x^3\ne0 \Rightarrow x\ne-4$

Now conclude the maximal domain:

$\boxed{x\in(-\infty,-8)\cup(-8,-4)\cup(-4,8)\cup(8,\infty)}$

Comment: Alright thanks. I got another question, so when I face similar questions like this, we usually do not touch the numerator, instead we look at the denominator if its equal to zero, not equals to zero, more or less than zero etc am I right?

So how do I determine if it's equals or not equals to zero in this case?

Comment: You need to find the values of $x$ that cause the denominator to be zero. I like the inequality idea, but you can also set equal to $0$.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't matter if it's equals or not equals to zero, am I right? So can I totally ignore the numerator at all while finding maximal domain, or is there some reasoning behind I should be following?

Comment: @mathlove agree, it is x $\ne $ -4.

Comment: @mathlove edited the post.

Comment: So can I totally ignore the numerator at all while finding maximal domain, or is there some reasoning behind I should be following?

Is there any method to identify my maximal domain?

Comment: Yes, for finding the domain of a rational function, you only have to examine the denominator.